# Issue with copying _PublishedWebsites folder from drop location during TFS Post-build scripts

Tags: powershell, build, tfsbuild, post-build-event

I have created one build definition in TFS, which is configured to run post-build powershell scripts.
The PowerShell scripts are expected to create a "Package" folder inside drop folder, and within the "Package" folder I want to copy a "Database.Upgrade" folder from source code, and published version of website from drop location itself.

I can see the "Database.Upgrade" folder is getting copied successfully, however, the "_PublishedWebsite" folder is not getting copied at all.

What could be the possible reason? Is the "_PublishedWebsite" folder not getting created before the post-build scripts?

```
# Pick drop folder
$DropFolder = "$Env:TF_BUILD_DROPLOCATION"

# Set Package folder (i.e., \\drop-location\Build name\Build number\Package)
$PackageFolder = "$DropFolder\Package"
$PackageFolder_Website = "$PackageFolder\MyApplication.Web"
$PackageFolder_Database = "$PackageFolder\MyApplication.Database"

if (!(Test-Path -path $PackageFolder)) 
{ 
    New-Item $PackageFolder -itemtype directory -force 
}

if (!(Test-Path -path $PackageFolder_Website)) 
{ 
    New-Item $PackageFolder_Website -itemtype directory -force 
}

if (!(Test-Path -path $PackageFolder_Database)) 
{ 
    New-Item $PackageFolder_Database -itemtype directory -force 
}

# Pick web deployment (published) folder (i.e., \\drop-location\Build name\Build number\_PublishedWebsites)
$PublishFolder = "$DropFolder\_PublishedWebsites\MyApplication"

# Copy published folder to package folder
Copy-Item $PublishFolder\* "$PackageFolder_Website\" -Recurse -Force

# Pick sql database scripts (i.e., App.Database.Upgrade folder) from TFS sources directory
$DatabaseScriptsLocation = "$Env:TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY\MyApplication 2016\Trunk\App.Database.Upgrade"

# Copy sql database scripts to database drop folder
Copy-Item $DatabaseScriptsLocation\* "$PackageFolder_Database\" -Recurse -Force
```

Here, the first Copy-Item is not really copying anything which is supposed to copy contents from _PublishedWebsite\MyApplication to Package folder, whereas, the second Copy-Item is working which successfully copies database upgrade scripts.

My build server is using TFS 2013.

Comment: Try using TF_BUILD_BINARIESDIRECTORY as the root location to pick up your web application from.  You drop location is the target UNC share for your build drop.

It looks like your $PublishFolder is point at the drop folder and the drop folder is not created until near the end of the workflow.  The Build process by default overrides $(OutDir) on MSBuild to point at the binaries directory

Comment: Correct, I am now able to copy the compiled version of the website using the variable you have suggested. Please paste this as an answer, and will mark it. thanks

Comment: Glad you are unblocked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using TF_BUILD_BINARIESDIRECTORY as the root location to pick up your web application from.  You drop location is the target UNC share for your build drop.

It looks like your $PublishFolder is point at the drop folder and the drop folder is not created until near the end of the workflow.  The Build process by default overrides $(OutDir) on MSBuild to point at the binaries directory.